# ETags on IIS 7.0

Tags: iis, etag

Are Etags on by default in IIS? If no then please let me know how to turn them on??

Comment: They are on by default and IIS 8.0 onward support turning off ETag altogether: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947420/iis-7-5-remove-etag-headers-from-response

Answer (score 5):

Etag is on, and set to 0 by default.

http://attosol.com/etag-and-iis-demystified/

Comment: But if it is set to 0 by default and IIS simply returns 0 for every resource in every request then I can't use ETag as it will never change even if the resource expires. This means I can't use the ETag header with its default values. I'm wondering why are we saying that it is ON then? I will consider the feature as ON only if the default installation of IIS 7 does send the ETag header value as 0 in every response without doing any additional setting. Is that the case? Although it will not be useful in the way it is ON if that's the case.

Comment: It'll be surprising if IIS 7 is returning this header without making explicit setting in default installation.

Answer (score 2):

ETags are "on" by default. People have problems turning them [*off*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477913/how-do-i-remove-etag-headers-from-iis7)...

Use fiddler and take a look at the headers for static content.