# URL Rewrite and IIS Express: some rules work, some don't

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, iis-express

I'm using IIS Express to develop an MVC 3 application which is doing some URL rewriting in web.config. I have ran into a bit of an oddity where some of the rules work perfectly, while others fail.

For example this one works:

```
<rule name="Remove ETag">
 <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_ETag" pattern=".+" />
 <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
</rule>
```

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8089525/88709)

This one doesn't (gives `Unrecognized attribute 'url'` in the second line):

```
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)/$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

(source: http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2009/04/08/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks.aspx)

According to [Introducing IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx), by ScottGu, IIS Express enables a full web-server feature set – including SSL, **URL Rewrite,** Media Support, and all other IIS 7.x modules.

I was inclined to believe that maybe the URL Rewrite module that ships with IIS Express is the 1.0 version, not 2.0. So I installed [URL Rewrite Module 2.0](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite), but I still get the same error.

Does anybody have a clue why this happens? In case it matters, my setup is Visual Studio 2010 SP1, IIS Express 7.5.1070, ASP.NET MVC 3.

Comment: works fine on my IIS Express:s You are probably getting this error from another code.

Comment: @tugberk I just created an new empty MVC project, left everything default, and added just the Remove trailing slash rule to web.config. Same error. Are BOTH rules working on your IIS Express? This is weird. I'm starting to think there's something wrong with my setup...

Comment: I have written a blog post about it and I all tested it on IIS Express: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/remove-trailing-slash-from-the-urls-of-your-asp-net-web-site-with-iis-7-url-rewrite-module cannot figure out what could be wrong :s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I placed the `<rule>` in the wrong node; 'Remove trailing slash' rule is supposed to go inside `<rules></rules>`, but I incorrectly placed it in `<outboundRules></outboundRules>` (which BTW is where the 'Remove ETag' rule goes).