# How to remove the HTTP ETag header by IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis, header, etag

We wish to remove the ETag header added automatically by IIS 7.5. None of the online suggestions worked for us, which may be due to a different version of IIS.

One of the solutions we have come across repeatedly included creating a new ETag HTTP response header with `""` as value. This approach adds `, ""` after the original ETag instead.

Comment: serverfault.com welcomes you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS 7.5 remove etag headers from response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947420/iis-7-5-remove-etag-headers-from-response)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been able to remove the ETag HTTP header using an [outbound rewrite rule](http://thethoughtfulcoder.com/blog/70/How-to-remove-the-IIS-ETag-HTTP-header-in-IIS-7-75-75).