# Is there a module to stop 304 Last-Modified checks?

Tags: c#, iis-7, asp.net-4.5

I have certain files that I know won't ever change or if they do we would create a new file and reference that version.

Now currently we are receiving 304 request to check if the file has been modified which I would prefer to eliminate.

If there any module I can add into my site or example code to create a module to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I am just spouting rubbish, but I believe that these requests are due to etags, which IIS almost always pumps out, so the client will always do a head request to check to see if the etag still matches... I asked a question about this a while ago if this is your problem:

[IIS 7.5 remove etag headers from response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947420/iis-7-5-remove-etag-headers-from-response)

Comment: Yes there is an e-tag in the request I will try removing them

Comment: Yes it was the e-tag and the rewrite rule corrected it.  I knew it would be something simple :)

Comment: Always is :), E-tags are notoriously difficult to remove from IIS responses, glad it helped.