# Enable text compression on an IIS server

Tags: iis, text, compression, pagespeed

When I do the test with PageSpeed, a section appears indicating that I must enable text compression.

I am using an IIS server, which has already configured the option to compress, but how do I enable it for the web I am testing?

In the list of files that I must enable, the domain appears, two CSS files and one JS file.

Thank you

Comment: Have you enabled Gzip compression?

Answer (score 0):

The section indicating that you must use text compression is asking you to enable one of the following: gzip, deflate, br etc.

You are looking to enable gzip compression on your server there is a thorough set of answers located at the following link (links to a stack overflow question with multiple good answers on how to enable gzip on IIS):-

[How to enable GZIP compression in IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580078/how-to-enable-gzip-compression-in-iis-7-5)

Answer (score 0):

According to official document, you only have to enable http static compression for your website.

To ensure IIS will compress FILE correctly, please ensure IIS static content feature has been installed(**IIS->World wide web Services->Common HTTP Feature->Static Content**). 
Please go to web browser developer tool  and check what's the content type is.

[image]

Secondly, please install IIS compression in I**IS->World wide web service->Performance feature->Static Content Compression.**

After installing IIS, please ensure **IIS manager->site level->Compression->Static Content Compression** has been checked.

Then Please access your website and check whether **Content-Encoding** has been displayed in response header.

[image]

If the response header is not displayed there, please check whether your content type has been set in **IIS manager->configuration editor->system.webServer/httpCompression->staticTypes** Collection.