# Issue with setting ETag in IIS

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I am trying to turn ETag on IIS, without success. I face the same issue both in my local IIS server (version 10) and remote IIS (version 8.5).

I have read many articles (like https://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/iis-8-0-to-use-or-not-to-use-etag-that-is-the-question) and stackoverflow questions (like [IIS 7.5 remove etag headers from response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947420/iis-7-5-remove-etag-headers-from-response)) without any solution so far.

This should be enough in the web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
     <staticContent>
       <clientCache setEtag="true" />
     </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But it is not setting on Etag, I cannot see in the list of browser's response headers the Etag.
Is there something else that needs to be taken in account, in IIS-settings?

Can anyone figure out what should be done?

Comment: Content type matters. Are you aware that this setting only applies to static content? If you're expecting to have an `ETag` response header for a dynamic content like [tag:asp-classic], it's not gonna happen.

Comment: I have to humbly admit, that no I was not aware that is only applies to static content. Well, now Etag is sent with response headers. Thank you!