# How do you properly handle caching static web content?

Tags: javascript, html, caching

Browsers cache static files. It's what they're designed to do. 99% of the time, that's a good thing. Until we as developers update that static content.

If a developer updates a javascript file, but a user's browser pulls the cached version of it, then:

- Best case, it'll be missing some new functionality until the browser decides to update its cache
- Worse case, if you also updated the html page to call a javascript function that didn't exist in the older version of the javascript file that the browser cached, your page breaks

As developers, we know to hit Ctrl+Shift+R, or Ctrl+F5, or open dev console, disable cache on the Network tab, and reload. But users don't know that.

What is the best practice to handle updates to static content?

- Is it to make sure that when you add new functions to a `.js` file, you push out the update to production a few hours/days before you update the html to call that function in `<script>` tags, allowing browsers to updated their cache over that time?
- Is it to not call javascript functions from HTML within `<script>` tags at all?
- Is there a way to somehow force browsers to expire cache on a specific static file when you update it?
- Something else?

Obviously disabling all caching on your site is possible, but not a realistic solution.

PS. I'm not using any kind of frontend framework - just raw javascript/jquery. If the situation is different with frontend frameworks, I'd love to heard about that too at a high level

Comment: See [here](https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/) for a description of a fairly standard approach. By using immutable static files and linking to them with always-revalidated html files you avoid both the best case and worst case problems you list.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the JavaScript file to be updated for the user when you update. you should use service work API to create a cache version for specific files or use the Google workbox library. [click here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox). for service worker API [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)

Comment: Definitely haven't heard of either of these. Will be looking into them.  Thanks. BTW the first link doesn't seem to point anywhere.

Comment: oh sry, my bad, [https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox), if you need more help you can find my in telegram with @realattila ID

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago [`location.reload(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) allowed bypassing the cache like <kbd>CTRL / Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> does. Only Firefox continues to support this feature by now, but the hard reload using javascript is no longer supported on chromium based browsers. ([spec doesn't describe this feature (anymore)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#dom-location-reload))

- This change was also discussed on this issue on [github/Microsoft/TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28898) and several other places on the web.

jQuery uses a simple workaround to be compatible with almost everything. If you load something with jQuerys [`jQuery.ajax({ url, cache: false })`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings), it appends a `_=TIMESTAMP` parameter to the url, which has a similar effect but may bloat the cache.

You can make use of the Entity tag header ([ETag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag)). Entity tags are similar to fingerprints and if the resource at a given URL changes, a new Etag value must be generated by the server, which is a similar behavior to the Last-Modified header. ([caniuse:etag](https://caniuse.com/?search=etag))

- Entity tags in: [Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37499383/10304804), [IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157292/etags-on-iis-7-0), [nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24555092/10304804) ([nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#etag)), [nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/etag)

It is also possible to clear the sites cache with a [`Clear-Site-Data: "cache"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/clear-site-data/) header. ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data), [caniuse:clear-site-data](https://caniuse.com/?search=clear-site-data))