# Yslow performance improvements in the web.config

Tags: performance, optimization, web-config, etag

Running my site on IIS7 and looking to improve my Yslow rating. Working with asp.net.

I am able to cache static resources in the web.config but is it possible to the following also:

Set the etag on the resources eg. javascript, images, css files etc
Add expires header to the above static resources
Set gzipping on components

Previously I use to use httphandlers to achieve the above but if its possible to set it up in the web.config it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you cannot set your etag values in your web.config and have it work.
Check out [How do I remove eTag headers from IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477913/how-do-i-remove-etag-headers-from-iis7) for more information. You can try setting a blank etag via IIS however to remove it completely.